# Product Facet not shown when exactly 1 value is present - Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Spartacus v 3.1
**Problem**
In SOLR response of PLP when there is a facet being returned with only 1 value and 1 count (e.g. Camera : Sony(1)). While this facet is appearing in the response , the facet is not being displayed in the facet component.

Is this a normal OOTB behavior of the product ?
If yes, Any means to override this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer here for Reference

https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/6600

The (current) backend returns facets with values that do not contribute to the facet navigation much, as the number in the result list will not get affected when they got applied. A ticket has been created to optimise this behaviour in the backend.

As long as this is not in place, we manually filter the facet from the list; any facet that does not have a count < the total results will be dropped from the facets.

PR for this fix https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/6600